# Switching from HDD to SSD failed. Could I migrate programs to the SSD and keep the HDD as the boot drive?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive, ssd

I'm attempting to repurpose an old HP pavilion laptop as a host for virtual machines like a proxy or pihole.

Unfortunately the screen won't work. I managed to convert it to Linux and set up remote access before the screen died. When I tried upgrading to an SSD clone of the hard drive I could not remotely access it. I've tried using a separate screen via hdmi but it won't work.

Luckily after removing the optical drive I have a second SATA port, so I can plug in two drives.

What could I realistically move to it via remote access? Virtualbox at least, hopefully. Would virtualbox work any faster that way?

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; that is likely the first detail required.  Virtualbox is generally not seen as the most efficient virtual platform.

Comment: I am not sure how to give a good answer to that. Practically, you can move to the SSD anything, including the complete system. And you already did the latter. The only question is "can you debug a problem without a screen?". And yes, you can move the virtual machines to the SSD by modifying `/etc/fstab`, as well as any other directories where VB is installed. Anyway, what I'd really suggest in your case: try connecting the cloned SSD system to the computer you're sshing from, and try booting from it. So you can debug any boot problems, resolve them, and then put the SSD back to laptop.

Comment: If it’s running some sort of Linux and you can ssh into it you don’t need Virtualbox. It’s probably much easier to use docker.

Comment: It does seem unfortunate that both the screen is broken *and* you can’t use an external screen. There’s usually a function key to select the graphics output … when you’ve connected your external screen via hdmi, see if there’s a function key to toggle the output - I think it’s fn-f4 for an hp pavilion. It’s not what you’re asking but would make things a lot easier. Just seems unlikely that there are 2 independent problems meaning no way to see a screen on the local system.